# What is an appropriate interface for dealing with meta-aspects of classes?

Tags: c++, metadata

I'm looking for some advice of what would be an appropriate interface for dealing with aspects *about* classes (that deal with classes), but which are not part of the actual class they are dealing with (meta-aspects). This needs some explanation...

In my specific example I need to implement a custom RTTI system that is a bit more complex than the one offered by C++ (I won't go into why I need that). My base object is `FooBase` and each child class of this base is associated a `FooTypeInfo` object.

```
// Given a base pointer that holds a derived type,
// I need to be able to find the actual type of the
// derived object I'm holding.
FooBase* base = new FooDerived;

// The obvious approach is to use virtual functions...
const FooTypeInfo& info = base->typeinfo();
```

Using virtual functions to deal with the run-time type of the object doesn't feel right to me. I tend to think of the run-time type of an object as something that goes beyond the scope of the class, and as such it should not be part of its explicit interface. The following interface makes me feel a lot more comfortable...

```
FooBase* base = new FooDerived;
const FooTypeInfo& info = foo::typeinfo(base);
```

However, even though the interface is not part of the class, the implementation would still have to use virtual functions, in order for this to work:

```
class FooBase
{
   protected:
     virtual const FooTypeInfo& typeinfo() const = 0;
     friend const FooTypeInfo& ::foo::typeinfo(const FooBase*);
};

namespace foo
{
    const FooTypeInfo& typeinfo(const FooBase* ptr) {
        return ptr->typeinfo();
    }
}
```

Do you think I should use this second interface (that feels more appropriate to me) and deal with the slightly more complex implementation, or shoud I just go with the first interface?

---

**@Seth Carnegie**

> This is a difficult problem if you don't even want derived classes to know about being part of the RTTI ... because you can't really do anything in the `FooBase` constructor that depends on the runtime type of the class being instantiated (for the same reason you can't call virtual methods in a ctor or dtor).

`FooBase` is the common base of the hierarchy. I also have a separate `CppFoo<>` class template that reduces the amount of boilerplate and makes the definition of types easier. There's another `PythonFoo` class that work with Python derived objects.

```
template<typename FooClass>
class CppFoo : public FooBase
{
  private:
    const FooTypeInfo& typeinfo() const {
        return ::foo::typeinfo<FooClass>();
    }
};

class SpecificFoo : public CppFoo<SpecificFoo>
{
    // The class can now be implemented agnostic of the
    // RTTI system that works behind the scenes.
};
```

A few more details about how the system works can be found here:
► https://stackoverflow.com/a/8979111/627005

Comment: I assume all the classes that will partake in your custom RTTI must inherit from `FooBase`. Would it be a problem to, instead of having each class override the virtual function to give their type, call a constructor `FooBase(int)` with a unique ID and have that initialise a member `const int`, so that the function `foo::typeinfo` is just a variable retrieval instead of virtual function call?

Comment: @SethCarnegie Part of the reason I need a custom RTTI is that my program embeds Python as a scripting language, so the RTTI system needs to be consistent across the two languages. There might be a few problems that arise with keeping the IDs unique between the two languages. [cont'd]

Comment: @SethCarnegie [cont.] There's also the problem that what you suggest introduces some boilerplate. I don't want the script-defined types to have to deal with any implementation details like this one; currently you just write the class as you would in a normal Python app and I'd like to keep it that way.

Comment: This is a difficult problem if you don't even want derived classes to know about being part of the RTTI (for me, anyway) because you can't really do anything in the `FooBase` constructor that depends on the runtime type of the class being instantiated (for the same reason you can't call virtual methods in a ctor or dtor).

Comment: @SethCarnegie I gave a few more implementation details my post.

Comment: solution: write all boilerplate code using http://nedbatchelder.com/code/cog/

Comment: @lurscher That's an interesting tool, but I don't think it's useful in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You can tie dynamic type with static type via `typeid` keyword and use returned `std::type_info` objects as means of identification. Furthermore, if you apply `typeid` on a separate class created specially for the purpose, it will be totally non-intrusive for the classes you are interesed in, althought their names still have to be known in advance. It is important that `typeid` is applied on a type which supports dynamic polymorphism - it has to have some `virtual` function.

Here is example:

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <cstdio>

class Base;
class Derived;

template <typename T> class sensor { virtual ~sensor(); };

extern const std::type_info& base = typeid(sensor<Base>);
extern const std::type_info& derived = typeid(sensor<Derived>);

template <const std::type_info* Type> struct type
{
  static const char* name;

  static void stuff();
};

template <const std::type_info* Type> const char* type<Type>::name = Type->name();

template<> void type<&base>::stuff()
{
  std::puts("I know about Base");
}

template<> void type<&derived>::stuff()
{
  std::puts("I know about Derived");
}

int main()
{
  std::puts(type<&base>::name);
  type<&base>::stuff();

  std::puts(type<&derived>::name);
  type<&derived>::stuff();
}
```

Needless to say, since `std::type_info` are proper objects and they are unique and ordered, you can manage them in a collection and thus erase type queried from the interface:

```
template <typename T> struct sensor {virtual ~sensor() {}};

struct type
{
  const std::type_info& info;

  template <typename T>
  explicit type(sensor<T> t) : info(typeid(t))
  {};
};

bool operator<(const type& lh, const type& rh)
{
  return lh.info.before(rh.info);
}

int main()
{
  std::set<type> t;
  t.insert(type(sensor<Base>()));
  t.insert(type(sensor<Derived>()));

  for (std::set<type>::iterator i = t.begin(); i != t.end(); ++i)
    std::puts(i->info.name());
}
```

Of course you can mix and match both, as you see fit.

Two limitations:

- there is no actual introspection here . You can add it to `template struct sensor` via clever metaprogramming, it's very wide subject (and mind bending, sometimes).
- names of all types you want to support have to be known in advance.

One possible variation is adding RTTI "framework hook" such as `static const sensor<Myclass> rtti_MyClass;` to implementation files where class names are already known and let the constructor do the work. They would also have to be complete types at this point to enable introspection in sensor.